# Rigidbody.MovePosition is teleporting character instead of smoothly moving?

Tags: virtual-reality

I'm trying to get a climbing system working in a no gravity environment for a VR game. I've been trying to debug this for the past day and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using

```
RigidBody.MovePosition(character.rotation * -velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

I use the XR controller velocity value to move the character the opposite way over time, but it's just teleporting the character instead of moving smoothly.

This is my code,  the inputdata is another script I'm accessing that just gets all the values for the controllers. I've tried addforce instead of moveposition but I'm not getting the type of movement I'm looking for. I want a nice climbing system to use. Please help!

```
public class LeftClimber : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody character;
    private InputData _inputData;
    public InputActionProperty velocityLeft;

    public bool touching;

    void Start()
    {
        _inputData = GetComponent<InputData>();  
        touching = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        touching = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        touching = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        _inputData._leftController.TryGetFeatureValue(UnityEngine.XR.CommonUsages.gripButton, out bool grip);

         if(grip){
            if(touching){
                Climb();    
            }
            
        }
    }

    void Climb(){
        Vector3 velocity = velocityLeft.action.ReadValue<Vector3>();
        character.MovePosition(character.rotation * -velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        
        Debug.Log(velocity);    
    }
}
```